# *** missing separator make error

Tags: makefile

I have tried to create a makefile to compile my C program. However, when I execute the `make` command in the terminal I keep getting this error:

`makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

This is my makefile:

```
CC= gcc -Wall
LIBS = -lm
HEADER_FILES_DIR = ./headerFiles
INCLUDES = -I $(HEADER_FILES_DIR)
MAIN= ejecutable

SRCS = asignarElemento.c destruyeMatriz.c main.c prodEscalar.c suma.c
creaMatriz.c imprimeMatriz.c obtenerElemento.c producto.c
DEPS = $(HEADER_FILES_DIR)/matriz.h
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCLUDES)
```

I have tried substituting the tabs by \t, changing the location of my header file... but I don't get it to work. The project does compile on Netbeans and Visual Studio, so it has to be a makefile problem.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your sources need to continue on the same line using the `\` character

```
SRCS = asignarElemento.c destruyeMatriz.c main.c prodEscalar.c suma.c \
creaMatriz.c imprimeMatriz.c obtenerElemento.c producto.c
```

Comment: Well, that was it. Thanks for the help!